# How to get full title of website in google custom search api?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-custom-search, page-title

This is my code.

```
def google_search(query, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=app.config.get("GOOGLE_API_KEY"))
    res = service.cse().list(q=query, cx=app.config.get("GOOGLE_CSE_KEY"),**kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

response = google_search(query, num=pageSize, start=start)
for item in response:
    print('Title: ', item['title'])
```

The result is like the following:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, one of the titles ends with "...". It is omitted.
But I want to get full title from the result.

I tried to get full title using selenium. But it takes long time.

```
def get_full_title(title, url):
    if title.endswith("..."):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        fullTitle = driver.title
        driver.quit()
        return fullTitle
    return title
```

So I thought, selenium is not the solution.

How to get full title?
Is there any setting to get full title in programmable search engine?

Comment: In your `google_search` function you're returning `res['items']`, and then using `items['title']` to get the title. Could you share what else is in the res and item dictionaries? I wonder whether there could be more information in there that might solve your problem.

Comment: title, htmlTitle, snippet, htmlSnippet, link, pagemap (metatag is included, some item dosen't have metatag info), ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL available in the item list, you can use `requests` and `bs4` (BeautifulSoup) to get the title pretty quickly:

Install requirements:

```bash
pip install requests
pip install bs4
```

Code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# If you need to fake a browser request
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


def get_page_title(url: str) -> str:
  response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser")
  return soup.title.string

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901995/how-to-get-full-title-of-website-in-google-custom-search-api"

title = get_page_title(url)

print(title)
```

Running for the current SO page returns `python - How to get full title of website in google custom search api? - Stack Overflow` (no ellipsis).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But I have used requests, mechanize, urllib, there were failed to get full title.
The website which I am going to scrap prevent bot and scraping, so I used selenium.

Comment: Selenium is also a bot. The only way the website would know that a request is coming from `requests` would be if you used the default header. By changing the header you should be able to get through.

Comment: @JGC “*The only way the website would know that a request is coming from requests would be if you used the default header.*” A biiiiiiig [citation needed] on this one - not correct at all. For starters, browser fingerprinting and SSL profiling exist and are used extensively behind the scenes for these types of big web properties to protect data and enforce ToS, likely among other heuristic analyses.

Comment: @esqew - Thanks for the correction. Would it be fair to say that some websites rely on user-agent to determine if a request is coming from a bot, so it might be worth a try changing it?

Comment: @JGC, I have tried, but not working. there is robots.txt in website. I tried to send get request with custom user-agent, but returns access-denied response.